# Changing the nth-child() attribute with @media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, css-selectors

I am currently trying to change the nth-child() attribute with @media queries but for some reason the media query is not affecting it. I'm trying to do something like this.

```
@media all (min-width:641px) {
   .photo:nth-child(4n) {
       margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
   }

@media all (min-width: 1000px) {
   .photo:nth-child(3n) {
       margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
   }
```

It is not changing from (4n).

Does anyone have any idea whats going on? Am I over looking something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're missing the closing brace of the `@media` blocks.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not changing from (4n)."? Do you mean the (4n) is still taking effect and you want to cancel it out in the second rule?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your initial definition for `.photo:nth-child` is after media queries definition in cascading and it's overridden. If yes, remove media queries after or try to put `!important` after definition.

Also consider if you wanted `min-width` or `max-width`.

These are only assumptions on first impression. Problem's not that clear...

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't make it clearer, you did help me find the answer though. thank you!